# Break debugging after a TRACE call

Tags: c++, debugging, trace

Is it possible to break debugging as TRACE(the debugger message output macro) is called, the message from trace appears on output, but I am unable to break the debugger as it does. (Am using visual studio 2003/windows).

I do not have the source code for this application. I'm simply attaching to the process.

Comment: I guess that macro calls `OutputDebugString`. Try setting a breakpoint on this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Put a breakpoint on one of your TRACE calls. Do whatever you need to do to make it fire. `Step In`. Put another breakpoint in that code. Remove your first breakpoint.</strike>

**Edit:** Put a breakpoint on the `OutputDebugStringW` and `OutputDebugStringA` APIs in kernel32.dll - it's those APIs that the TRACE macro calls.

In the Breakpoints window, go New / Break at Function, and enter `_OutputDebugStringW@4`.  Repeat for `_OutputDebugStringA@4`.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry I should have been more specific, I edited the question.

Comment: thanks a lot!, a `GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle( "kernel32.dll" ), "OutputDebugStringA" )` indeed solved it! (will accept as soon as so allows)